# NystedBerry.Silverlight.Controls.ScrollableDataGrid LoadingRow does not exist in release

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2013

Just upgraded to VS 2013.

I have a SilverLight ScrollableDataGrid that has a LoadingRow event in debug.
In release the control has no events. Builds just fine in Debug.

I'm looking at the events in the Object Browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up changing reference ver in the *.csproj file.

OLD:

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Data, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

NEW:

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Data, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```